# How to avoid encoding parameter when opening file in Python3

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, python-import

When I am working on a .txt file on a Windows device I must save as either: ANSI, Unicode, Unicode big endian, or UTF-8. When I run Python3 on an OSX device and try to import and read the .txt file, I have to do something along the lines of:

```
with open('ships.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        print(line)
```

Is there a particular format I should use to encode the .txt file on the Windows device to avoid adding the encoding parameter when opening the file in Python?

Comment: You can use an encoding-guesser, or add a BOM to the files to be read

Comment: @Ni. Adding a BOM won't help.  `open` doesn't use them for encoding detection.

Comment: @Mark Tolonen yesterday Right, but I think maybe `encodings` library has an open function that uses BOMs

Answer (score 0):

Call `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` on your OSX device.  That's the default encoding used for reading a file on that device.  Save in that encoding on Windows and you won't need to specify the encoding on your OSX device.

But as the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) says, "Explicit is better than implicit."  Since you know the encoding, why not specify it?